# Why only one column is generated after write.csv from a complex data frame in R?

Tags: r

I want to export the data frame I generated with R into a csv file. However, this code gives me the whole data frame into only one column:

```
   tableausublist <- read.csv("donnees/sublist.csv", header=TRUE, sep=";")
   fusion <- merge.data.frame(x=tableaucleanIPTAFXwoNA,
   y=tableausublist, by.x="Description", by.y="protein", all =FALSE)

   tableauIPTAFXreorder <-fusion[,c('complex','Accession.x','Description', 'meanNSAF','SDNSAF')]
   write.csv(tableauIPTAFXreorder,"IPID.csv")
```

Comment: Could you show the code for generating the data? Or some description of it?

Comment: Is `tableauIPTAFXreorder` a dataframe? `str(...)` Please edit your question (add more infos)!

Comment: Considering the fact that you tagged this question with 'Excel', this question might seem less stupid :
How did you check that the output is only one-column ? If you opened it with MS Excel, maybe you should also check the default separator.

Comment: Yes I want to get a table that I can open  with Excel. So, after write.csv in R I checked with Excel.

Comment: @Vongo is right, Excel opens csv files as a single text column. You need to separate it using "Text To Columns" in the "Data" tab.  Also look into  `write.table` should you need to use another separator (`sep =`)

Comment: sorry, but I do not understand. Because when you open an .xlsx file saved into .csv file, you keep the different columns. So, I do not see why here, it opens into a single column...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A strong guess based on the comments above: try `write.csv2` rather than `write.csv`.  From `?write.csv`:

> ‘write.csv2’ uses a comma for the decimal point and a semicolon
>        for the separator, the Excel convention for CSV files in some
>        Western European locales.

Comment: Great! I was not aware of such differences between the different versions across the world... So, .csv2 works well, I get the final table I was expecting. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Open your .csv-file in a text editor and check for column and line separators as well as for decimal point (esp if you are working on non US regional settings)